# running a nodeJS function within a csv file

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, express, axios

I have a nodeJS app in which I designed it to run three API calls based on the name of the business and return results.   What i want to do is run this app in a CSV file that I have.   Below is my code.  Any ideas on how to do this?  Below is a sample of my code.   Im trying to run the name column, pass it inside my functions and return the results inside the CSV file.

```
function fetchYelp() {
    let token = '<Token>';
    axios.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=Grace Christian Fellowship&location=Mounds, il 62964',{
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    })
        .then(res => {
            if(res.data.businesses.length < 1){
                fetchWhitePages();
            }else{
                console.log(res.data.businesses);
                console.log('running YelpAPI')
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}
fetchYelp();


function fetchWhitePages() {
    axios.get('https://proapi.whitepages.com/3.0/business?api_key=<key>&address.city=Mounds&address.country_code=US&address.postal_code=62964&address.state_code=il&name=Grace Christian Fellowship')

        .then(res => {

            if(!res.data.business.length < 1){
                fetchGooglePlace()
            }else{
                console.log(res.data);
                console.log('running whitePagesAPi')
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
}

function fetchGooglePlace(){
    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Grace Christian Fellowship, mounds il 62964&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry,place_id&key=<APIKEY>')

        .then(res => {
            if(res.data.candidates.length < 1){
                console.log('Manual Search')
            }else{
                console.log(res.data.candidates[0].place_id);
                console.log('Passing Place ID to fetchGoogleTel')
                fetchGoogleTel()
            }

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
}

function fetchGoogleTel ()
```

Comment: A csv is not typically executable.  Why do you want to run javascript 'in' a text file, rather than reading in the file, making the api calls, then saving the output to the file?

Comment: Hi! I want to be able to read the cvs file, pass in that data to my api call and then write back that data to the cvs file.

Comment: I recommend you start by reading about how to read in the data from a csv in javascript, once you can console.log the correct results, then try to add the step 'append to a csv file from javascript'.  You probably don't need to make many changes to the code you already have, just break down the problem to In and Out parts and create read and write methods.  This may help you get started https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/reading-csv-file-using-javascript-html5/

Comment: Great, thank you so much.